File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, global-set-key
I wanted to customize the key binding of emacs with a simple set of key binding that we all use in every application. for example for the cut, copy paste etc.
SO I created a init file in
/home/my-user/.emacs.d/init.el 

and added those lines (a subset given google Gemini)
(require 'global-set-key)
(setq default-frame-alist '(
  (fullscreen . maximized)
))
(setq inhibit-startup-message t)

;; Basic mappings
(global-set-key (kbd "C-o") 'find-file)

;; Remap save and open
(global-set-key (kbd "C-s") 'save-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-w") 'save-buffer-as)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-f") 'isearch-forward)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-h") 'replace-string)

;; Remap undo and redo
(global-set-key (kbd "C-z") 'undo)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-y") 'redo)

;; Remap cut, copy, and paste
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x") 'kill-region)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c") 'copy-region-as-kill)
;; (global-set-key (kbd "C-c") 'kill-ring-save)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-v") 'yank)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-a") 'beginning-of-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-/") 'comment-region)
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'indent-region)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x <") 'indent-less)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-g") 'goto-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x 2") 'split-window-horizontally)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x 3") 'split-window-vertically)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x 0") 'delete-window)

but the problem is emacs can not seem to find global-set-key anywhere.
so I started commenting lines from the init file but nothing seem to work. Gemini thinks that global-set-key is a function and not a file (so I can not find it anywhere on my system). but the error message from emacs clearly thinks that it is a file.
⛔ Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/home/adeelaz/.emacs.d/init.el’:

File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, global-set-key

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace.


“a subset given google Gemini” - I suggest you learn some ELisp by yourself first, so that you can at least have the basic judgment of the code given by AI.  ||| Just delete the first line.

global-set-key is a function, not a file, and is built-in to Emacs. Do C-h f global-set-key to find out about it. As everybody has indicated, the require is not only unnecessary, it is what produces the error you get.

In addition, wholesale remapping of keys for basic functionality is positively harmful. If you have a problem, you will have to go through extra layers of translation in order to explain to somebody else what the problem is and/or read documentation: in particular, the tutorial assumes that you haven't changed key mappings. You should delete all of that, learn how to use Emacs first with the default key mappings and then decide on how to change them. Some of your mappings are contradictory: C-x cannot be bound to a function like kill-region and at the same time act as a prefix.

Please delete everything from your code shown that's irrelevant - 90% of it. Thx.

You should delete (require 'global-set-key) as the function global-set-key is already built in. The require makes Emacs try to load global-set-key as a module, which, as global-set-key is a function, does not exist.
